# Why does Ubuntu GNOME recommend make?

Tags: gnome, apt, package-management, package-info

Running `apt-cache depends ubuntu-gnome-desktop` lists, among other things, GNU Make as a recommend. `apt-cache depends gnome` doesn't list Make.

Why? It doesn't seem like Make and GNOME would be in any way related (apart from their origins at GNU, if I'm not mistaken).

Answer (score 0):

Maximum compatibility for existing sources. Lots of sources out there and most of them need make to compile. So doesn't it make sense to go with maximum compatability?

Comment: but I shouldn't need to compile anything; this makes no sense. stuff should already be in the APT cache/archive.